# How does the const keyword affect a pointer that is pointing towards a const variable?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

If you consider this:

```
int *var1;
const int *var2 = var1;
```

Why does

```
*var1 = x;
```

compile and

```
*var2 = x;
```

does not?

Comment: that's what const is for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case

```
 *var2 = x;
```

fails to compile with error message (*approx*),

> error: assignment of read-only location `*var2`
>
> ```
>  *var2 = 10;
>        ^
> ```

because you have marked the value to be of `const` qualified.

---

To elaborate, you can read a statement like

```
  const int *var2;
```

as, *declare `var2` as pointer to `const int`*. So the value pointed to by `var2` is constant and cannot be changed.

In case you want the pointer itself to be const-qualified, you need to write something like

```
 int * const var2;
```

which basically is declaring `var2` as `const` pointer to `int`.

So, later any attempt to *assign* to `var2` will produce the error, but accessing `*var2` will work fine, as the value pointed to by the pointer is not const-qualified anymore.

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation is what I read in text book.  But if you read the compilation error message literally, that does not  make a sense at all.  Here is why.   int x;  int *px = x;  const int *cpx = px;   Lets say x occupies in address of 100.  That means px will have value of 100.  The memory address of 100 is not in read-only location.  The compilation error message is not only misleading, but absolutely wrong. It should say something like "Cannot modify a value using const int *".

Comment: @Nguaial and why is that? I find it pretty accurate. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your explanation is accurate.You did a great job!!!!  But I am complaining about the compilation error message. The part about "assignment of read-only location ‘*var2’".  It should be more like "Cannot assign a value using const int *.".

Comment: @Nguaial I guess it's a matter of choice, Compiler is tailing you that the location `*var2` is read-only, so there should be some reason for it. `const` qualified is one of them, so I guess that's it. :)

Comment: @Nguaial Agree that "error: assignment of read-only location '*var2'" mis-leads.  It is a compilation error even if the location was write-able.  `const int *` describes the pointer `var2`, not the memory it points to.

Comment: @SouravGhosh    *var2 - trying to assign a value at the memory location which is stored in var2  variable.  So lets say var2 has value of 100 which is write-able memory.  So technically, *var2 = 100 should be allowed.  That statement is not changing the value of var2, but it is changing the value that is stored in the memory address of 100.

Comment: @Nguaial You think "read-only location" means "location in read-only memory", but actually it just means "location forbidden to be written to *through this pointer*". Const-qualification always follows the pointer (or variable), not the object.

Comment: @trentcl - Yes.  I am with you on that. I guess I am being too literal with the compilation error message.  I just feel that the error message is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of const int * in this context helped me to understand:

```
int 
sum( const int *x, const int *y )
{
    return *x + *y;
}

int
main(void)
{ 
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int sum;

    sum = sum &x, *y );
}
```

By putting const int * qualifier at functional arguements, this is saying that the value x and y are immutable(not modifiable) inside the function.

But other than this usage, I find const int * very confusing.